Не появляется slash команда в списке комманд бота
Я написал слеш команду, ее код ниже
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
class wantrole(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.slash_command(
            name = 'test',
            description='Сменить гендер пользователя'
    )
    async def test(ctx):
        await ctx.send('привет', ephemeral=True)
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(wantrole(bot))

бота запускаю, но команда почему то не появляется вообще, пробовал также заходить через браузер, там тоже ничего нет, в чем может быть ошибка
в консоли ничего по поводу этого не написано
Добавлено:
Создал бота с другого аккаунта, там команда почему то есть

Убедись, что ты подгрузил cog в основном файле бота, где лежит bot.run() и переменная bot.

Иногда также необходимо заходить в настройки сервера, так как Discord не видит новых команд бота.
"Настройки сервера" -> "Интеграции" -> имя бота -> команда, в которой произошла ошибка -> "Переназначение ролей"
Поставь, сохрани, потом убери, чтобы Discord подгрузил команду на сервере.

Еще можно поставить test_guilds = [guild_id] в переменную bot, где guild_id - это ID твоего сервера.
